# How to display current filters applied without affecting the graph in dc.js?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

In the below link when i select something the filter gets displayed but the chart does not changes

here is my jsfiddle link: jsfiddle.net/amru/t56z8w2w/3/

Comment: @Emzor now you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Filters [do not apply to groups](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group) defined on the same dimension as the filter. Define another chart based on a different dimension and it should change when you make a selection.